# Physical states are primary and space-time is secondary

Tags: quantum-mechanics, foundations

This is pure speculation. The title of the question is a quote from [Zeidler's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540347623) book on QFT p.141:

> In the setting of noncommutative geometry, physical states are primary and space-time is secondary.

This is around the discussion of sub-Planck length and time scales. However, for the simplest case of nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, quantum states live in an appropriate Hilbert space. Could this is be a reflection in some nonrelativistic limit of the above quote, or is it more that we "do not" know how to build a proper quantum theory? For more arguments, observables are operators which also live in an abstract (Lie algebra) space.

Comment: I think you confuse the state/operator space with physical space-time.

Comment: I don't think so, check again the quote. I'm trying to make sense if there is some trace of what is quoted in nonrelativistic QM. If so, please point out where do you consider there is a source of confusion (because to me is clear and makes sense).

Comment: But the Hilbert space/Lie algebra space has nothing to do with the physical spacetime. This is what i meant.

Comment: Yes! Precisely this is my question regarding the quote: the state $|\Psi\rangle$ that lives in a Hilbert space knows everything, while a particular projection like $\langle x| \Psi\rangle$ knows only of the behaviour on position. In this regard, $|\Psi\rangle$ is more general than choosing a specific representation in space-time. Connecting to the quote, the Hilbert space in a way is more general than a specific space-time representation.

Comment: Notice that the Hilbert space is related to the space-time via a projection $\langle x| \Psi\rangle$. Thus, they are not completely separate issues but can be "glued" toghether....

Comment: Why would the position representation $\Psi(x)=\langle x|\Psi\rangle$ know only about position? It still contains all information contained in $|\Psi\rangle$.

Comment: It is just the expansion of the state vector in terms of a certain basis (leaving aside the technical bits about the definition of states like $|x\rangle$).

Comment: viz, a cat state aligned in $p$ direction looks different in $x$ and $p$, but the state has the information of the whole distribution... If I give you $\langle x| \Psi\rangle$ (not $|\Psi\rangle$!), probably you cannot tell me which kind of state is, you will only see a "coherent state".

Comment: Ok, but why would you only consider a specific coefficient $\Psi(x)$? This has nothing to do with the spacetime issue. You could equally well say that only knowing the projection of an isopin state on an arbitrary basis state (which is purely internal and hence not spacetime related) also does not contain all information.